# Error oracle sql developer "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: oracle

I am getting this error using oracle sql developer for the query below and can't really figure out what is wrong with it. 
"SQL command not properly ended"

select * 
from Table1
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

Comment: I am using this version  4.1.3.20

Comment: No, I mean ORACLE version.

Comment: Please run this statement and see what it tells you: `SELECT * FROM v$version
WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';`

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: OK, so you have your answer. FETCH... was introduced in Oracle 12.1.

Comment: what should I upgrade ? because I am confused between the versions

Comment: As an aside, if you are using it for free (for personal evaluation and learning), you may upgrade for free to Oracle DB 12c Enterprise Edition (I didn't know that either till a few days ago).

Comment: I used to use SQL studio now i switched to oracle sql developer. what would you suggest for me to get familiar with it.

Comment: SQL developer is not the database software, it is only the interface you use to interact with it. Every version of Oracle DB (including 12c) comes with its (upgraded) SQL Developer. I use SQL Developer perfectly fine, both with Oracle 11g (on my laptop) and with 12c (on my desktop) - all for learning, I am not an IT professional.

Comment: One last question please, with what can replace fetch(...) that would do the same thing in my version of oracle ?

Comment: Not clear what you were doing in the first place.... if there is no ordering and you just want to pick a (random) row, you can say WHERE ROWNUM = 1. If you do want an ordering, you will need to add `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... (analytical clause here) AS RN` to the `SELECT` clause, and then select from this (as subquery) `WHERE RN = 1`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What version of Oracle are you using? `FETCH (...)` is only available in Oracle 12.

Please run this statement and see what it tells you:

```
SELECT * FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';
```

Comment: I am using this version 4.1.3.20

Answer (score 5):

After 5 years this question doesn't have a full answer except what is in the comments. Credit to @mathguy for the answer. You can do this

```
SELECT * from Table1 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ROWNUM < 10
```

These will give essentially random rows but generally this is just used for data exploration anyway, so not a big deal. If you want one specific row then use something like this:

```
WITH X AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeField) FROM table1
)
SELECT * FROM X WHERE RN = 1`
```